Selecting Button with Puppeteer or Triggering Download
I've been using puppeteer a lot lately and have been able to click other buttons, traverse through the DOM, etc with no problem.
However, I ran into one specific button that I haven't been able to click or interact with for some reason. Puppeteer can't even find it when I use waitForSelector. I can see the button visually on the page and I monitor the network requests so I know that it's not waiting for the network.
It's not in an iframe, and I checked to see if there was any shadow-dom component to this and I didn't see anything.
Here is the button:
<button data-bind="click: handleBulkDownload, visible: showDownloadAll(),
 attr: { 'data-ga-click': gaTabName + 'Download All Attachments',
 'data-ga-tab': gaTabName }" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="font-size: 12px;" title="Videos cannot be downloaded at this time." data-ga-click="Download All Attachments" data-ga-tab="">
    <img data-bind="visible: isBulkDownloading" src="/images/Common/spinner.gif" alt="Downloading" style="display: none;">
    Download All <span data-bind="text: downloadAllText">(18)</span>
</button>

Do you see anything weird with this or have any ideas on what to check for? Also I would settle for triggering the download action that is tied to this button, but I haven't had much success with that either.
Thanks!

There's not much context here. Looks like a normal button to me pretty much. How are you selecting this? Is it actionable/visible and properly waited for, and you're sure the site isn't blocking your script in any way? Please share a [mcve]--code with a site I can execute to see the problem occur, or provide a workaround to get to your fundamental goal in some other manner. Thanks.

@ggorlen you are right, this was pretty vague and I was just hoping to jog my memory on something I may have overlooked. Thanks for your effort, it did in fact help in the end

No problem, but feel free to update the question so it's reproducible. This helps future users that might have the same problem as you and provides context/motivation for your answer. Otherwise it's specific to whatever your hidden page is doing and doesn't add much value to the site, unfortunately, since only you could have possibly known/figured out the answer.

@ggorlen I understand that and would do so, but this button is buried so far deep in HTML that it wouldn't be reasonable to paste that all here unfortunately.

That's why sharing the actual site is the way to go! Also, I'm surprised the tree would be that deep. We have a warning about this in the canonical web scraping FAQ.

I ended up needing to navigate further down the DOM to a parent element that didn't have so much stuff in it. Then, I waited for a button to populate within that specific parent div:
                await myPageSection.waitForSelector('button', { timeout: 15000 }).catch(() => {
                console.log('No buttons found within pageSections[3] after waiting.');
            });

And finally, I ran through all the buttons to find the one I needed. I think classes and innerText were dynamically changing, which is part of the reason why I couldn't target it:
const allButtons = await myPageSection.$$('button')

